Laravel 10: Session regeneration in middleware not updating values
I am working on a Laravel 10 application with middleware that checks if a token has expired. If it has, it generates a new token using refresh_token, creates a new session, and updates the session with the new data (token, refresh, and expires_at).
Middleware
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Nanicas\Auth\Services\ThirdPartyAuthService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NanicasAuthenticateMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $auth = $request->session()->get('nanicas');
        if (empty($auth)) {
            return $this->logout($request);
        }

        if (!Carbon::now()->greaterThanOrEqualTo($auth['expires_at_datetime'])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $config = config('nanicas');

        $authService = app()->make(ThirdPartyAuthService::class);
        $authResponse = $authService->refreshToken([
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'client_id' => $config['CLIENT_ID'],
            'client_secret' => $config['CLIENT_SECRET'],
            'refresh_token' => $auth['refresh_token'],
            'scope' => '',
        ]);

        if (!$authResponse['status']) {
            return $this->logout($request);
        }

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $request->session()->put('nanicas', $authResponse['body']);

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->forget('nanicas');

        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return $request->expectsJson() 
            ? response()->json(['message' => 'Token expirado'], 401) 
            : redirect()->route('login');
    }
}

I am using this middleware on the HOME route like so:
Route::middleware('auth.nanicas')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});

My Laravel session lasts two days, but the internal token I use for authenticating to an external API expires every two hours. When the token expires and I refresh the HOME screen, the session retains the old values instead of the newly updated ones. This only happens when I use $request->session()->regenerate(). If I remove this line, everything works as expected.
According to the Laravel documentation, regenerate() is used to regenerate the session ID. However, the documentation doesn't explain the impact this has on the application.
Can anyone explain why the session isn't updating with the new values when I use regenerate()? Also, I noticed that commenting out the \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class middleware in the web group generates some random IDs. Could this be related to the issue?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78305978/laravel-get-old-session-id-on-refresh

Instead of using any method like dd(), var_dump or something that would dirty the screen or stop my application just for debugging, I decided to use the class: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log and do the registry silently, having the expected result.
Note: I continue using $request->session()->regenerate();, the session is being "regenerated" and my user continues to be logged in as if nothing had happened.
[2024-04-12 13:20:58] local.ALERT: {"before":"kgZAcuh9vMPGxtuZCboKTGrbqLGPnwVaCZW0yuMT"}
[2024-04-12 13:20:58] local.ALERT: {"after":"kyoN8Jn679Vg26iubIfzGTcucS5e2uILtdbFDDBi"}

[2024-04-12 13:21:22] local.ALERT: {"before":"kyoN8Jn679Vg26iubIfzGTcucS5e2uILtdbFDDBi"}
[2024-04-12 13:21:23] local.ALERT: {"after":"iuZXh6PPzx0KyCXuCKynBxLb5SqxuZDDkpFsYAPc"}

[2024-04-12 13:21:29] local.ALERT: {"before":"iuZXh6PPzx0KyCXuCKynBxLb5SqxuZDDkpFsYAPc"}
[2024-04-12 13:21:30] local.ALERT: {"after":"1OvaFxmwzR2YO1d9NCKSHqFwhD7Nw1phIBUNpRY2"}

[2024-04-12 13:21:34] local.ALERT: {"before":"1OvaFxmwzR2YO1d9NCKSHqFwhD7Nw1phIBUNpRY2"}
[2024-04-12 13:21:35] local.ALERT: {"after":"CP3OStFiPwl4SaHLlig6nkei1VOexrWOt1HHygse"}

Note that the value of the "after" key will always be equal to the value of the "before" key of the next block.
Now I ask you, why would dirtying the screen with debug results impact the set-cookie or the way Laravel responds to the browser about session persistence?
