Laravel get old session id on refresh
Good afternoon,
I have the following code:
// routes/web.php

Route::get('/', function () {
    print_r(['start' => session()->getId()]);
    
    session()->regenerate();
    
    print_r(['after start on /' => session()->getId()]);
    print_r(session()->all());
    
    sleep(5);

    return redirect('/get');
});

Route::get('/get', function () {
    
    print_r(['end on /get' => session()->getId()]);
    print_r(session()->all());
});

The following result:


Why doesn't Laravel get the UPDATED ID when I access /get?
What am I doing wrong?
The value lrTifbBYDeX8ihhUBwa4nnTWiOncWnVZmXXChHHk is returned :(
I want to update my session and use the new ID value from now on.
The middlewares being used are these:
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

Reference: Renegerate session is getting old values on Laravel
I tested using Laravel 10, Laravel 9 and Laravel 8, they all behaved the same.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78303780/renegerate-session-is-getting-old-values-on-laravel

you can use this:
session()->invalidate();

but remember that you will log out the user by running this. if you want to user still be loged-in, you have 2 solutions:

you can use another cookie for your purpose and let session to be unchanged:

cookie(['foo' => 'bar']);


just after invalidating the user's session, regenerate a new session and log in the user with that session (i don't recommend that if you don't know exactly what are you doing because of security concerns):

$user = auth()->user();
session()->invalidate();
session()->regenerate(); // may be this line is not necessary!
auth()->login($user);

hope helps.

So, I can't this, because my user need to stay logged without notice that your token was update internally.

the session is a cookie that saved in the user's browser. with session()->invalidate() you tell the user's browser (via HTTP headers) that it must delete its session cookie because that  is not valid anymore.
Laravel detects users by its session cookies, so, when you change the user's session key, you cant expect it logged in anymore.
I will update my answer to solve your problem.

Your solution works fine. But, I noticed that my problem was not about the flow and methods, my problem was about printing something during the executation. I removed all var_dumps and replaced to Log::info, and all worked as expected using just session()->regenerate(). Thank you very much.

Now I ask you, why would dirtying the screen with debug results impact the set-cookie or the way Laravel responds to the browser about session persistence?

Honestly, I don't know exactly what could be the reason, but i know that the session change is done after returning the controller functions (through headers). I think it is more likely that this happened because of the way the functions returns. (for example, the second function does not return anything).
